# Find all numbers $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(z−i)^5 = \sqrt{3} +i$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

This is a follow-up question to finding all solutions for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^5 = \sqrt{3} +i$ but I have no idea how to approach this question (might just be having a brain fart)

The only way I can think of solving it would be to expand it into a polynomial and then solve for z but that seems like a lot more work than necessary, and I would think this answer would have something to do with my answer to the previous question.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.If you can make $\sqrt{3}+i$ into polar form, then it will be easy for you to remove the exponent.

The way to convert it is very simple: $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}^2+1^2} e^{i(\tan^{-1}(3^{-0.5}))} = 2 e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}}$.

So if we write $(z-i)^5 = 2e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}}$, then taking fifth root on both sides and then adding $i$, we get:

$z = i + \sqrt[5]{2}e^{\frac{(12n+1)i\pi}{30}}$, $n=0,1,2,3,4$. These are the solutions, you can now expand out the $z$ and get the roots more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

If $w^5 = x$ then $z = w+i$ satisfies $(z-i)^5 = x$, and conversely. In other words, add $i$ to your solutions to the previous problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generalize the problem, solve $\text{z}$ when $\text{a}\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $\text{b}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}^+$:

$$\left(\text{z}-\text{a}i\right)^{\text{n}}=\text{b}\Longleftrightarrow\text{z}=\left|\text{b}\right|^{\frac{1}{\text{n}}}e^{\frac{1}{\text{n}}\left(\arg\left(\text{b}\right)+2\pi k\right)i}+\text{a}i$$

Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-(\text{n}-1)$.

Comment: Would you then go onto convert your "ai" into polar form to try get a singular term answer? I'm working on a question where I get z = e^(i(π/8 +kπ/2)) + i, using your method.

Comment: @Skylineblue Show me the original problem...!

Comment: Well, this is for an assignment and I'd prefer not to write the question as I don't want someone solving it all for me. But the question is (z-i)^4 = i. Any **hints** would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write $\sqrt 3+i$ in exponential form., and you'll find out it's a problem of finding the $5$th roots of a complex number with modulus $1$.